# Loss oscillate instead of decreasing seq2seq gru pytorch

Tags: pytorch, loss, seq2seq

I'm trying to build seq2seq model with attention on Pytorch gru for sentiment extraction.
Example of sentiment extraction:
Input1: 'sooo sad i will miss you here in san diego!!!'
Target1: 'sooo sad'
Input2: 'my boss is bullying me...'
Target2: 'bullying me'

My model:

```py
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, dropout_odds=0.2):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_odds)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(embedding_size, hidden_size, bidirectional=True)
        self.fc_hidden = nn.Linear(hidden_size*2, hidden_size)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(x)).view(1, 1, -1)
        output, hidden = self.gru(embedded)
        hidden = self.fc_hidden(torch.cat((hidden[0:1],hidden[1:2]),dim=2))
        
        return output, hidden

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_size, hidden_size, dropout_odds=0.2):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout_odds)
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_size)
        self.energy = nn.Linear(hidden_size*3, 1)
        self.gru = nn.GRU(hidden_size*2+embedding_size, hidden_size)
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, vocab_size)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax_en = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
        self.softmax_out = nn.Softmax(dim=2)

    def forward(self, x, hidden, encoder_outputs):
        embedded = self.dropout(self.embedding(x)).view(1, 1, -1)
        sequence_length = encoder_outputs.shape[0]
        h_reshaped = hidden[0].repeat(sequence_length, 1)
        energy_ = self.relu(self.energy(torch.cat((h_reshaped, encoder_outputs), dim=1)))
        attention = self.softmax_en(energy_)
        context_vector = torch.einsum("st,sh->th", attention, encoder_outputs)
        output = torch.cat((context_vector.unsqueeze(0), embedded),dim=2)
        output, hidden = self.gru(output, hidden)
        output = self.out(output)
        return output, hidden

class Seq2seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder):
        super(Seq2seq, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        
    def forward(self, source, target, teacher_force_ratio=0.5):
        sourse_len = source.shape[0]
        target_len = target.shape[0]
        target_vocab_size = vocab.n_words
        encoder_outputs =  torch.zeros(sourse_len, hidden_size*2, device=device)
        decoder_outputs = torch.zeros(target_len, 1, target_vocab_size, device=device)
        for ei in range(sourse_len):
            encoder_states, hidden = self.encoder(source[ei])
            encoder_outputs[ei] = encoder_states
        x = target[0]

        for t in range(1,target_len):
            output, hidden = self.decoder(x, hidden, encoder_outputs)
            decoder_outputs[t] = output
            best_guess = output.argmax()
            x = best_guess

        return decoder_outputs

hidden_size = 1024
embedding_size = 1024
epochs=100
encoder1 = Encoder(vocab.n_words, embedding_size, hidden_size).to(device)
attn_decoder1 = Decoder(vocab.n_words, embedding_size, hidden_size).to(device)
model = Seq2seq(encoder1,attn_decoder1).to(device)
# optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=0.05)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
training_pairs = [tensorsFromPair(pair) for pair in pairs]

model.train()
for epoch in range(1,epochs+1):
    print(f"[Epoch {epoch} / {epochs}]")
    
    indx = 0
    for tp in training_pairs[:100]:
        
        inp_data = tp[0]
        target = tp[1]
        
        output = model(inp_data, target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(output.squeeze(1), target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        indx+=1
        if indx%100==0:
            print('loss: ',loss)
```

training pairs are list of tensors, each tensor contains a pair of tensors each element are index of word in vocab:

```py
training_pairs[0] = (tensor([18, 19, 20, 21, 22,  1]), tensor([21, 22,  1])), where 1 EOS_token
```

For some reason when the model learns loss does not decrease, but oscillates:

```
[Epoch 1 / 100]
loss:  tensor(974.1525, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 2 / 100]
loss:  tensor(5.4103, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 3 / 100]
loss:  tensor(3404.2073, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 4 / 100]
loss:  tensor(5.4103, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 5 / 100]
loss:  tensor(2543.9885, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 6 / 100]
loss:  tensor(28.9650, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 7 / 100]
loss:  tensor(2998.9417, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 8 / 100]
loss:  tensor(5.4103, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 9 / 100]
loss:  tensor(5.4103, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
[Epoch 10 / 100]
loss:  tensor(5.4103, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward>)
```

The situation repeats if you change input for encoder for SOS token.
I have also tried to calculate loss without an EOS token it does not change anything.
I can`t understand why the loss is calculated incorrectly.

Comment: An oscillating loss is often caused by a high learning rate. Try to reduce it maybe `0.01` or `0.001`.

Comment: It turned out that this is really the problem, I reduced the learning rate to 0.0001 and added a scheduler and everything works fine. TYVM